# Custom Permalinks for Blog Posts Only

Tags: url-rewriting

I know this is a fairly common topic around here, but I can't seem to figure out a solution to my particular case from reading similar threads.

Basically, my permalink structure needs to be /%postname%/ for compatibility with a finicky plugin. The plugin authors may fix this in the future, but for now I need to come up with my own solution. The problem is, I want my blog post urls to be /blog/%postname%/. I need some way to hook into the URL rewriting for just the `post` post type and change the permalink structure from /%postname%/ to /blog/%postname%/.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing permalink structure to `/blog/%postname%/`?

Comment: @rilwis, yes, and that structure works perfectly. The problem is that I'm also using Shopp (1.2 Beta) plugin, and for some reason Shopp breaks completely with any permalink structure other than /%postname%/. I know, they should fix this on their end, but I have no idea how long that will take (or if they even will fix it), so I'm trying to find my own work around.

Comment: Well, I never found a solution to this, but I wound up switching from Shopp to WooCommerce. So, my permalinks are working perfectly now. Thanks to everyone who helped on this.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, so your question does not haunt site as unanswered.

Comment: @Rarst, as I said in my comment, I never found a solution for this unless you consider giving up on the problem a solution. If you like, I can post that I gave up and switched plugins so I wouldn't have to solve this as a solution.

Comment: Well, as I saw it switching from Shopp **was** the solution for you. :)

Comment: @Rarst, good point. Looks like we got a legitimate answer after all though, so problem solved. Btw, I know this isn't really the place for this, but I'm really struggling with the performance of a `WP_Query` meta query. If you wouldn't mind taking a quick look at that question, I would love to get any thoughts you might have: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8893160/931860.

Comment: Yeah, meta queries that complex are complete drag on performance. I hadn't had to deal with such myself so far so don't have good suggestion.

Comment: I was kind of afraid you'd say that. Thanks for taking the time to look at it for me though. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even though this is no longer a problem for you, I decided to pursue it for purely academic reasons. I got it working by prepending rewrite rules and filtering permalinks. Note that I wouldn't actually recommend doing this, but it's fun to know it's possible :)

```
function filter_post_link($permalink, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type != 'post')
        return $permalink;
    return 'blog'.$permalink;
}
add_filter('pre_post_link', 'filter_post_link', 10, 2);


add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_blog_rewrites' );
function add_blog_rewrites( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'blog/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive list of rewrite rules. Thanks for taking the time to sort through this. I'm sure it will come in handy for someone down the line. I haven't tested this solution myself, but it looks great.

Answer (score 0):

If other people are looking for it, here is a variation of Matthew answer (which work perfectly) to achieve this:

Blog archive : `/blog/`

Blog category : `/blog/category-name/`

Blog post : `/blog/category-name/post-name/`

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_blog_rewrites' );
function add_blog_rewrites( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'blog/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?taxonomy=category&term=$matches[1]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?taxonomy=category&term=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/])+/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]'
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

With `/%category%/%postname%/` for the permalink structure and this for the categories links:

```
function filter_category_link($permalink, $term) {
    if($term->taxonomy !== 'category') {
        return $permalink;
    }
    return 'blog' . str_replace('category/', '', $permalink);
}
add_filter('pre_term_link', 'filter_category_link', 10, 2);
```

Comment: What's the advantage to this one over Matthew's answer?

Comment: @Tobe_Sta This is explained on the top of my answer...