# Do the permalink settings apply to pages as well as posts?

Tags: pages, permalinks

I want to have all my blog posts have the structure http://mysite/blog/blogarticle1 but I want the pages to have the structure http://mysite/page1 (no "blog" in there). I see how to include "blog" in the permalink settings but I'm not sure if those settings apply to the pages as well (which I don't want). Please advise. Thanks!! :-)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/custom-permalinks-for-blog-posts-only

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be to set your permalink settings to /%category%/%postname%/ and just assign all of the blog posts to a category of "blog"

Comment: So would my pages still stay as http://mysite/pagename (e.g. http://mysite/contact) then? It's not clerar to me if the Permalink settings are supposed to apply to pages as well as posts or just posts. Thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: Yes, the permalink setting do apply to pages. With the /%category%/%postname%/ structure, your pages will create a hierarchical permalink. mysite.com/page1/subpage/subpage/

Comment: @PNMG this is not a good suggestion... blog is not a category but a is a page in theory... making blog as category will give you problem in the future if the site wishes to change theme...